# Syntax error for string member variable in class

Tags: c++, string, class, syntax-error

This program is meant to convert Roman Numeral to the equivalent decimal number.  I understand the logic in the following code is no where near where it needs to be to function properly.  However, I am just trying to get the class members set up properly before working on the algorithm and I am getting a syntax error in reference to the private member romanNumeral defined as a string type.  The following shows my code as well as the error messages I am receiving.

**Header File - roman.h**

```
class romanType
{

public:
    void storeRoman();
    void convertRoman();
    void printRoman();
    romanType();

private:
    string romanNumeral;
    int decimal;

};
```

**Implamentation File - romanImp.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "roman.h"

using namespace std;

void romanType::storeRoman()
{
    // Promt user to enter roman numeral and store
    // in romanNumeral variable member
    cout << "Please enter a Roman Numeral: ";
    getline(cin, romanNumeral);

    // Input Validation
}

void romanType::convertRoman()
{
    // When function is called, decimal starts at zero
    decimal = 0;

    for (int index = 0; index < romanNumeral.size(); index++)
    {
        switch (romanNumeral[index])
        {
            case 'M':
                decimal += 1000;
                break;
            case 'D':
                decimal += 500;
                break;
            case 'C':
                decimal += 100;
                break;
            case 'L':
                decimal += 50;
                break;
            case 'X':
                decimal += 10;
                break;
            case 'V':
                decimal += 5;
                break;
            case 'I':
                decimal += 1;
                break;
        }
    }
}

void romanType::printRoman()
{
    // Print roman numeral
    cout << "The Roman Numeral entered was: " << romanNumeral << endl;
    // Print deciaml
    cout << "This converts to " << decimal << " in decimal." << decimal << endl;
}

romanType::romanType()
{
    romanNumeral = "I";
    decimal = 1;
}
```

**Main source file**

```
// Project 4

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "roman.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    romanType testRoman;

    // Display default constructor values
    testRoman.printRoman();

    // Run program
    testRoman.storeRoman();
    testRoman.convertRoman();
    testRoman.printRoman();

    return 0;
}
```

**Error Messages:**

error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'romanNumeral'
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
error C2065: 'romanNumeral' : undeclared identifier

Comment: Have you placed `using namespace std;` in your roman.h file? If not, then change `string romanNumeral;` to `std::string romanNumeral;`

Comment: @JimmyThompson, I wouldn't even mention the option of putting the using directive in it. Putting those in headers is evil.

Comment: @chris Of course, I'm just bad at reading error messages so I have to ask. That's why I recommended changing it to `std::string` rather than simply adding the `using` directive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your roman.h file, you do not include the string class so I think that is one are where at least one of those errors will go away. Here is the code I used to get it to compile in codeblocks

```
#ifndef ROMAN_H
#define ROMAN_H
#include <string>

class romanType
{

public:
    void storeRoman();
    void convertRoman();
    void printRoman();
    romanType();

private:
    std::string romanNumeral;
    int decimal;

};

#endif // ROMAN_H
```

Comment: Note the std::string string is in the std namespace and also needs to be included in-order for everything to compile correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Add `#include <string>` to the top of `roman.h`, and use `std::string` instead of `string` in the class declaration.

Comment: Adding this code worked.  I didn't think it was necessary within the header file, but I guess I was wrong.  Thank you very much